# can't load packages using zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, graphframes

using a zeppelin notebook with spark, I want to load graphframes using the ui manager[image: loading graphframes]
After clicking save I get a prompt. I want to click okay to approve new settings and restart cluster, but the `ok` button is not responsive.
Note that when I change other settings without loading dependencies, it works fine.
[image]

Comment: graphframes is a spark package but not in maven central. Did you add the spark repository as well?

Comment: I did not. How would I go on doing so?

Comment: The Repository button is on the right corner of Interpreters if it's Zeppelin 0.7.1. Add https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/ as a repository

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer since I did not see it mentioned in the comments or in the linked questions.

One quick and easy (and probably dirty) way of adding a jar to Zeppelin (version 0.10.1 in my case) is to use `spark.jars` field after going to interpreter menu and editing the `spark` interpreter there.

You can enter the path to your jar file directly in there and it will be put on the class path and executor path automatically after the interpreter restarts. The only issue I had was it didn't give me an error when I entered the path wrongly. It just ignored the non-existent path which can lead to further troubles down the way.